# How to get access token in azure Active directory in Angular2

Tags: azure, active-directory, asp.net-core-1.0

I am starting to learn Oath 2, i need to get access token from the front end side(angular 2) with out showing the Microsoft login page,there have any option for that, if have please share me , Thank you.

Comment: Can you share with me how you did this. I am struggling to achieve this. I have put a bounty on a question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of token which Azure AD could issue.

First is the delegated token which used to delegate the sign-in user. And normally this kind of token required to users sign-in(**Authorization Code Grant flow**). However if there is a high degree of trust between the resource owner and the client, we can also use **Resource Owner Password Credentials flow** which using users' username and password in code directly without users participate.

And the second kind of token is delegated the application called app-only token. To acquire this kind of token, we can use the app's key or the certificate without users sign-in(**Client credentials flow**).

If you were developing with **Client credentials flow**, you can refer [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only) which acquire the token for Microsoft Graph using **Client credentials flow**.

### Update

To acquire the token using the **Client Credentials flow** for multi-tenant apps, we need to grant the permission to the application to register the service principal to the customers' tenant. We can use the **Code grant flow** to grant the permission. More detail about the multi-tenant apps, you can refer [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview/#related-content).

To init the **code grant flow**, you can refer the request sample from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code/). After the you grant the permission, the customer also could see this application on their portal. Then you can use the the **client credentials flow** to reacquire the token from customers' tenant.

Comment: Thank you So much the 2nd one working fine ,i am get the token from AD..

Comment: Then i have another query,as per you mention link ,that is for single tenant,if you don't mind can you tell me how to do in multi tenant as per the way..

Comment: I have updated the answer, please let me know if you still have the problem. And based on my understanding, this scenario is very special.